# Random username generator with random number behind errors

Tags: java

I have been on this for about an hour and I really can't figure this out, I am suppose to make something that prompts for and reads the user’s first and last name (separately).  Then print a string composed of the first letter of the user’s first name, followed by the first five characters of the user’s last name, followed by a random number in the range 10 to 99. and assume that the last name is at least five letters long

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //Needed for the Scanner class  
import java.lang.String;

import java.util.Random;

public class UsernameGenerator
{    
public static void main(String[] args)  //all the action happens here!    
{  Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();

    int num1;
    num1 = generator.nextInt(10-99);

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String concatenatedName;

    System.out.println("Enter your First Name: ");
    firstName = input.next();



    System.out.print( "Enter your Last Name: " );
    lastName = input.next();


    // We'll take the first character in the first name
    concatenatedName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 5) + num1;



    Random rnd = new Random(); // Initialize number generator
    if (lastName.length() > 5)
        concatenatedName += lastName.substring(0,5);
    else
        concatenatedName += lastName; // You did not specify what to do, if the name is shorter than 5 chars

    concatenatedName += Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt(99));


    System.out.println();

}
}
```

Comment: `concatenatedName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 5) + num1;` At this line, `concatenatedName` should contain the solution. Delete everything after that.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus I just compiled and got this error           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at UsernameGenerator.main(UsernameGenerator.java:24)
and now it says that concatenatedName is never read, sorry I'm extremely new to this :P

Comment: `generator.nextInt(10-99);` should throw an IllegalArgumentException. You cannot pass negative numbers to it. Change to `generator.nextInt(90) + 10`

Comment: You seem to have the entire logic (other than input) twice, as if you took two solutions and mixed them up together.

Comment: generator.nextInt(10-99) means your effectively doing generator.nextint(-89). When you've fixed this you should also add a print statement like System.out.println(concatenatedName) at the end.

Comment: @Quirliom that fixed my negitive number problem thank you! I am able to run it now but after I enter my first name and last name it just stops

Comment: Add a print statement for concatenatedName at the end of your function, you're currently not doing this.

Comment: You have `System.out.println();` so you print **nothing**.  It does not stop it's doing what it was told to do.

Comment: @PM77-1 Wow thank you everyone for the help guys it is 100% working thanks again everyone! :D

Comment: Method `substring` in your first version of concatenation will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if `lastName` is less than 5 characters. The second version takes care of it.

Comment: @Alex Nuff: Here's why I up-voted your post: Fantastic comment in the code!  // You did not specify what to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this to deal with the fact the lastname might not be 5 characters in length. The latter part of your function - where you set check the length and add another random number is not required.

```
    // We'll take the first character in the first name
    try
    {
        concatenatedName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.substring(0, 5) + num1;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Here we deal with the fact we might not be able to get 5 characters from the last name
        // - Just add the full lastname
        concatenatedName = firstName.charAt(0) + lastName + num1;
    }

    System.out.println(concatenatedName);
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be part of normal program flow. Instead, how about `lastName.substring(0, Math.min(5, lastName.length()))`?

Comment: I agree this would be a better solution - however it is also not ideal that the full solution is being performed in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

This will print what wanted at the end of your code, not a bad start, keep up the hard work

can anyone figure out this part? I am practicing (:

Then, if you like, enhance it so that if the last name is less than 5 characters long, it inserts extra random characters or digits so that the generated user name still contains 8 characters. This is an optional enhancement.

```
Random rnd = new Random(); // Initialize number generator
if (lastName.length() > 5)
    concatenatedName += lastName.substring(0,5);
else
    concatenatedName += lastName; // You did not specify what to do, if the name is shorter than 5 chars

concatenatedName += Integer.toString(rnd.nextInt(99));
System.out.println(concatenatedName);
```